# Where does Linux set the default values for SHMMAX?

Tags: kernel, memory, shared-memory

I'm just wondering where these values are being set and what they default to? Mine is currently 18446744073692774399. I didn't set it anywhere that I can see.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax 
18446744073692774399

$ sysctl kernel.shmmax
kernel.shmmax = 18446744073692774399
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `__init` function [`ipc_ns_init`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/ipc/shm.c?h=v4.11#n112) sets the initial value of `shmmax` by calling [`shm_init_ns`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/ipc/shm.c?h=v4.11#n75), which sets it to the value of the `SHMMAX` macro.

The definition of `SHMMAX` is in [`<uapi/linux/shm.h>`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/shm.h?h=v4.11#n21):

```
#define SHMMAX (ULONG_MAX - (1UL << 24)) /* max shared seg size (bytes) */
```

On 64-bit machines, that definition equals the value you found, `18446744073692774399`.

Answer (score 2):

On the fly you can just echo into /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax!

```
# echo 20446744073692774399 > /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
```

But most people edit /etc/sysctl.conf with a line similar to:

```
kernel.shmmax=your_new_value_here
```

See the sysctl(8) man page.

Comment: That's not the question. Where are the defaults set? That is, if you don't write to shmmax yourself, what does it default to?

Comment: On some Linux distros (RHEL 5&6 I believe is one) it is set in /etc/sysctl.conf. But I think the default is set in the kernel code to the theoretical limit (guessing that's 2^64 - 1?).

Comment: Wolfram-Alpha says: 2^64-1 = 18446744073709551615 which isn't the number he is looking for.